# View page based on a record

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP and pardon me for asking this very basic question. What I want to do is to display or view a page based on a specific record. For example, I have a home.php page which lists records of lessons. And when I click on a specific record, it will go a page named lesson.php . I have to view the relevant information/data from my dB of that specific lesson. I tried to use GET but I think it's not going to meet the requirement of my system.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 $qry1stQuarter = $conn->prepare("SELECT l.lesson_title FROM tbllessons as l
            JOIN tblstudents as s
            ON l.grade_level = s.grade_level
            WHERE quarter_code = '1st'
            AND s.grade_level=:grade_level");
  $qry1stQuarter->execute(array(':grade_level' => $grade_level));


 <div id="tabs-2">
 <div id="accordion">
 <h3><strong>Yunit 1</strong></h3>
 <div>
    <?php
    for($i=0; $row = $qry1stQuarter->fetch(); $i++){
       $lesson_title = $row['lesson_title'];
?>
    <div id = "lessons">
        <?php 
        echo "<a href = 'lesson_view.php'>$lesson_title </a>";?>
    </div>

<?php 
} // end of for loop
?>
 </div> <!-- end of Yunit 1 -->
```

What is the best way to do this? Your help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variables? But I strongly suggest that stick to `$_GET` variable for link jumps.

Comment: @ChristianMark can you give me some sample implementations of that? I find the examples here very confusing, and I want to try something like a query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database, I assume you have an ID column. A typical way to do what you are asking is to use that ID as a GET parameter on a link, and then include that in your `WHERE` clause in your SQL statement.

Eg:

```
echo "<a href='lesson_view.php?id=$lesson_id'>$lesson_title</a>";?>
```

And then on your lesson_view.php page, your SQL has something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbllessons WHERE id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])
```

Comment: Hey dude, I tried to put the $_GET['lesson_id'] in my lesson_view.php but it's not retrieving the id

Comment: @Dunkey Can you get more specific? Could be any number of things. Does the URL you're hitting have ?id=XX in it? Does your database have a corresponding ID column? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I found the error. I didn't change ?id=$lesson_id. So to fix this, I changed to ?lesson_id=$lesson_id